# Passing AIR value to javascript. How do I make it available to $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, air, document-ready

I need to get an absolute file path into the native AIR browser.  I've gotten the value of it,and the alert in my function called by the AIR app works fine, but can't seem to make it do anything.

How do I make siteRoot available to my $(document).ready function?

```
         function calledFromAS(test) 
            { 
                siteRoot = test;    
                alert(siteRoot);        
            }

        $(document).ready(function(){

        alert(siteRoot);
        })
```

EDIT:  much larger code snippet

from my Flex project (where calledFromAs() is called):

```
var filePath = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath;;

        function init():void {
            html.htmlLoader.window.calledFromAS(filePath);
        }
```

From the js file which builds the player and playlists:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


        //alert(siteRoot);

      // instantiate the player so that the playlist always exists

       var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_N",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
      }, [
      {
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
        //poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/poster/The_Stark_Palace_640x360.png"
    }
      ], {
        playlistOptions: {
        enableRemoveControls: true
         },
         swfPath: "js",
         supplied: "flv"

});




    //hide the player, display homepage content when user clicks home 
    $('#home').click(function(){


        //show home page content
        $('#homeContent').show();

        // remove hover state from all buttons but this one
        $(".button").removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("on");


        $('#player_container').hide();         

    })

    //############## begin full video player ############# //
    // instantiate player for full video content.  no playlist
    $('#fullVideo').click(function() {

            //show current video title before video is played
            $('#videoTitle').empty();
            $('#videoTitle').append("Full Video")

            // remove hover state from all buttons but this one
            $(".button").removeClass("on");
            $(this).addClass("on");

            //hide the home content, show the player instead
            $('#homeContent').hide();
            $("#player_container").show().addClass("player_container_1").removeClass("player_container_2");

            //set the playlist
             myPlaylist.setPlaylist([

    {
            title:"Full Video",
            //m4v:"http://dev.brandgnumedia.com/html5video/jplayer/vids/Forest_with_new_slides_NoQA_v2_011712_edits.mp4",
            flv: test + "jplayer/vids/Forest_with_new_slides_NoQA_v2_011712_edits_1.flv"

        }
        ], {
                });

             //hide the playlist
            $('.jp-playlist').hide();                

    });
```

Comment: where is the `calledFromAS()` called from? and why would you need it in `.ready()`?

Comment: sorry for the pseudo code.  calledFromAS() is called by an air app.  This script is running in an AIR browser.

I need it in .ready because I'm constructing a jPlayer playlist in .ready, and long story short, AIR doesn't support the <video> tag and jPlayer requires absolute file paths for flash media.  I have to find the location of the AIR app on the users hard drive, then pass that to .ready so that the player will find the media.

I'd go about this a different way, but I've already built a web app that I'm converting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, your Flash app needs to tell JS the path to your files.

To do this, you have to move your player script outside the `.ready()` and in to a separate function. then, have that function called from the AS script with your path passed.

```
function calledFromAS(path) { 
    //buildPlayer     
}
```

however, it's risky to assume that if your flash has loaded, all the DOM is loaded. you need to have a function in flash to be called from `.ready()` to tell flash that all of the DOM has loaded, and from there, have flash call the function above.

Comment: I'm already getting the file path.  That part works just fine, and the first alert does show the correct file path.  I'll try that approach, but jPlayer really wants to be built on .ready().  Maybe I can find a workaround for that.

Comment: the problem is you can't assume which loaded first. 1.) you could have flash be loaded first but the DOM incomplete. code in `.ready()` won't be executed until DOM is complete - in short, you can't assume a function made in `.ready()` is available when when your flash app loads. 2.) on the other hand, if the `.ready()` fires first, you built your player in it, but you don't have the path to your files.

Comment: Shows what I know.  jPlayer was fine with being built by calledFromAs() and is now finding the media.  Thanks for the help.  I'll also try to add your callback function to the AIR app as well.